# Convert en_US to to en-US

Tags: php, html, apache, lang

I'm writing a PHP application that supports multiple languages.

When setting the locale in PHP, I am required to provide a value defined in, what I believe to be, [RFC 1766](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1766.html) / [ISO 639](http://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/IG/ert/iso639.htm), according to the [*setlocale* documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'en_US' );
var_dump( setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, '0' ) );
// string(5) "en_US"
```

When using this locale to describe the HTML *lang* attribute, validation fails because it is not formatted to [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646). The RFC 5646 value for this language is actually `en-US` (note the use of a hyphen instead of an underscore).

Using this value in PHP's *setlocale* function, as above, results in the following output:

```
string(1) "C"
```

<del>I have no idea why it is returning a value of C, but I presume it is because the locale provided was incorrectly formatted.</del> *C* being the original server default, which is [described as ASCII](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) (thanks to  @Cheery for the reference).

So, I'm wondering what I should do about that. I could, feasibly, use PHP's *str_replace* function to switch `-` to `_` before outputting the *lang* attribute, like so:

```
<?php setlocale( 'en_US' ); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="<?= str_replace( '_', '-', setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, '0') ); ?>">
...
```

But, I'm concerned that there may be other differences between the two language specifications that could yield an unexpected problem down the road. If so, is there a preferred way to translate the language codes already in PHP, or a translation class that can be used?

Bonus question, why does my server default to value of *C* for the locale?

Comment: `C` is one of the system's locales. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale, for example. `C               # fall-back, ASCII encoding, same as POSIX
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have in mind that setLocal accept many types of "locale" names like names and mixed things, for example in (from php documentation):

```
$loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge');
```

You have 'de_DE@euro' which isn't a valid HTML lang code.

So first, you need to ensure that is in the format `lang_region` before trying to convert it.

Comment: Good point @PhoneixS. I didn't notice that additional formats that won't map to the HTML specifications. I should probably just maintain a dictionary of the different supported types and reference them as needed. Appreciate the reply!

Answer (score -1):

You can set local language codes using "**setlocale**".

[You can find here it's documentation as well as this and other examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)

Example where they try different possible locale names for german:

```
<?php
/* Set locale to Dutch */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nld_nld');

/* Output: vrijdag 22 december 1978 */
echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 22, 1978));

/* try different possible locale names for german as of PHP 4.3.0 */
$loc_de = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo "Preferred locale for german on this system is '$loc_de'";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I can set the locale using PHP's *setlocale*. The problem I'm running into is using that in the HTML *lang* attribute, since it uses a different format. I'm wondering if anyone knows the differences between the formats to know whether or not a simple string replacement ('_' to '-') will suffice.